# Problem with dynamic variable in C# | MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, object, dynamic, bson

I am writing this post today because I am currently stuck on a part of MongoDB

I want to upload a custom class, in a dynamic variable, but when I create a document on Mongo, the dynamic variable is converted to JSON object, how can I solve this problem?

My custom class :

```
public class Param
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Scope { get; set; }

    public dynamic Value { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime FirstIntegrationTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastIntegrationTime { get; set; }
}
```

The mongodb methode I'm using :

```
public async Task CreateParamAsync(Param param)
{
    await _collection.InsertOneAsync(param);
}
```

Result in MondoDB
[image: image here]

I tried to create a Bson in the dynamic variable Value, like that :

```
public async Task CreateParamAsync(Param param)
{
    param.Value = BsonValue.Create(false);
    await _collection.InsertOneAsync(param);
}
```

But I find myself with this :
[image: image here]

Comment: What is the column type in MongoDB?

Comment: @Brad this is a string type

Comment: Ok I fixed my problem, just use JsonSerializer.Deserialize and set my dynamic variable before it's created